# This code yields `0` as the value no matter what roman numeral I enter. Why is this so?

Tags: python-3.6

```
    import re
    d = { ' M ' :1000, ' CM ' :900, ' D ' :500, ' CD ' :400, ' C ' :100, ' XC ':90,
    ' L ' :50, ' XL ' :40, ' X ' :10, ' IX ' :9, ' V ' :5, ' IV ' :4, ' I ' :1}
    pattern = re.compile(r"""(?x)
                             (M{0,3})(CM)?
                             (CD)?(D)?(C{0,3})
                             (XC)?(XL)?(L)?(X{0,3})
                             (IX)?(IV)?(V)?(I{0,3})""")
   
    num = input( ' Enter Roman numeral: ' ).upper()
    m = pattern.match(num)

    sum = 0
    for x in m.groups():

        if x!=None and x!= '' :
            if x in [ ' CM ' , ' CD ' , ' XC ' , ' XL ' , ' IX ' , ' IV ' ]:
                sum+=d[x]
            elif x[0] in ' MDCLXVI ' :
                sum+=d[x[0]]* len(x)
   print(sum)
```

When I run this code it gives `0` as the output no matter what Roman numeral I enter.
What did I do wrong? Is white spaces the issue?
For example: Enter Roman numeral I
`0` Enter Roman numeral X
`0`

Comment: _Is white spaces the issue_ Did you try it without the white spaces?

Comment: I did try it without the white spaces but it still gives the same result. What else can be the issue?

Comment: It appears to work without the spaces: https://repl.it/repls/WellinformedHopefulCopycat#main.py

Comment: I used autopep8 to get it to conform with python3 standards. However, that did not seem to work. I have to see what error I have made on my part. Your solution works flawlessly. Thank you

Comment: I found the error. My indentation on the 5th to 8th lines was a bit off. I had to indent those lines a bit more.This was highlighted in your solution. I just did not notice it.